# Using Unit of Work pattern in Queueable Context

Tags: apex, sobject, compile-error, queueable

I'm trying to implement Andy in the Cloud's [Unit of Work](https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/06/09/managing-your-dml-and-transactions-with-a-unit-of-work/) pattern within a queueable class so that I can handle the DML for the `Milestones` that I'm inserting & relating to the `Projects`, which are also being created by this class, more easily. The `Milestones` are the children of `Projects`.

I'm hitting several errors:

> unexpected token: 'private'
>   unexpected token: 'static'
>   unexpected token: 'List'

for the line that begins `private static List MY_SOBJECTS`

&

> Invalid type: SObjectUnitOfWork

for the line `SObjectUnitOfWork uow = new SObjectUnitOfWork(MY_SOBJECTS);`.

```
public class CreateImplementationProjects implements Queueable {

  private Set<Id> stage4PlusOpportunities = new Set<Id>();

  // constructor
  public CreateImplementationProjects (Set<Id> stg4OppIds) {
    this.stage4PlusOpportunities = stg4OppIds;
  }

  public void execute (QueueableContext context) {

    List<Opportunity> changedOpportunities;

    changedOpportunities = [SELECT Id,OwnerId,AccountId
                              FROM Opportunity
                             WHERE Id IN :stage4PlusOpportunities];

    public static List MY_SOBJECTS =
    new Schema.SObjectType[] {
      MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c.SObjectType,
      MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Milestone__c.SObjectType
    };

    SObjectUnitOfWork uow = new SObjectUnitOfWork(MY_SOBJECTS);
    for(Opportunity o : changedOpportunities) {
      MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c project = new MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c();
        project.Name = o.Name;
        project.OwnerId = o.OwnerId;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use `private` & `static` collections in the queueable context?

And why is the compiler complaining about the `SObjectUnitOfWork`?

---

**Edit** To be clear, I have spent quite a while looking for the answers to those questions but can't find any information that's related, I'm not just posting this out of laziness!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed it to public in your code sample, but the principle is the same. When you are within a method definition, your syntax for declaring variables is different than at the class level.

At the **class level**, the syntax is for variable declaration is:

```
 access_modifier static_modifier variable_type variable_name;
```

You can optionally include assignment syntax at the end. This syntax is what you use for `stage4PlusOpportunities`, for example.

- `access_modifier` is `private`
- `static_modifier` is omitted, meaning it is an instance variable
- `variable_type` is `Set<Id>`
- `variable_name` is `stage4PlusOpportunities`

However, **within a method declaration**, neither `access_modifier` nor `static_modifier` are valid. So the syntax simply becomes:

```
variable_type variable_name
```

So proper declaration would be simply:

```
List<SObjectType> MY_SOBJECTS = new List<SObjectType> { ... };
```

Note that every `List<T>` must be specifically typed, in this case `List<SObjectType>`.

---

Since the information you are working with does not appear to be specific to the Queueable instance nor execution context, you should probably just move it to the class level.

```
public with sharing class MyClass implements Queueable
{
    public Set<Id> myOtherVariable = new Set<Id>();
    static final List<SObjectType> MY_SOBJECTS = new List<SObjectType> { ... }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

---

As for why the compiler complains that the `SObjectUnitOfWork` type is not defined, make sure the [`SObjectUnitOfWork`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-apex-enterprise-patterns/blob/master/df12/src/classes/SObjectUnitOfWork.cls) class is actually pulled into your org.

Comment: Thanks again. I think utilising the Unit Of Work is probably overkill for my use case here. But the notes on syntax declaration will be really useful to refer back to & I will move my information to the class level. Not my greatest question..

Answer (score 2):

You have to install [FinancialForce Apex Common library](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common) and also [ApexMocks](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks) that it dependant on.

Please reference the documentation from the above links to familiarise yourself with the functionality.